# The difference of wakelock core code and interfaces in kernel 3.0 from 3.7/3.8?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, power-management, wakelock

I was told that wakelock in kernel 3.7/3.8 is different from 3.0. What has changed and is there any document or discussion somewhere talking about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Cite your source of *told that wakelock in kernel 3.7/3.8 is different from 3.0*?

Answer (score 0):

I diff-ed wakelock.c from both kernel versions and they have many changes.  I am just looking for a brief and quick information what has been updated. Thanks